# what should be the object in JComboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue(object) to set fixed width of Jcombobox

Tags: java, swing, awt

I would like to set a fixed width for JComboBox, at present its width is setting based on maximum element length.I used JComboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("X").Now it is setting some width.But couldnot understand based on what width was set the to JComboBox.can any one help?

Comment: What's not clear from the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setPrototypeDisplayValue-E-)?

Comment: I used one x, then fixed to some width and in case of xxx also same width.Then what is exactly we need to sepcify?

Comment: Here's some [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bswing%5d%20setPrototypeDisplayValue)

Comment: @jenny, `I used one x, then fixed to some width and in case of xxx also same width` - The size changes for me when I use different string values. If it doesn't change for you they the problem is probably with your layout manager that is not respecting the preferred size of the combo box. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.